# Comparing leaf nodes of binary search and merge sort

Tags: binary-search, mergesort

For binary search, it forms a complete binary tree, so n = (2^k)-1. 2-way merge sort also forms a complete binary tree but n = 2^k, why is this? Why is it not also (2^k) -1?

Answer (score 0):

Because unlike in a BST, where the root is some number in your set, the root of the tree in a merge sort is nothing until you reach the end of the algorithm, when it becomes the whole list, which was merged from the sorted left and sorted right part of the list.
The `-1` in the BST formula is the first value, which we'll declare root of the BST.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing completely different things. Binary search works on a *sorted array*, not a tree. The array may have any length. At each step, it looks at the element closest to the middle and then - if that middle element is not the searched item - it recursively searches the left and right sublists.

Now it does turn out that if you happen to have an array of size 2^k-1, the math works out so that you'll always have equal numbers of elements on either side of the center. Why? At the base of the recursion you have the center element with zero on either side. At the level above the base, you have the center element with 1 on each side or 3. At the level above that you have 3 on either side of the center.  Continue in this vein:

```
base      0 + 1 + 0 = 1  = 2^1 - 1
level 1   1 + 1 + 1 = 3  = 2^2 - 1
level 2   3 + 1 + 3 = 7  = 2^3 - 1
level 3   7 + 1 + 7 = 15 = 2^4 - 1
level 4  15 + 1 +15 = 31 = 2^5 - 1
```

You can see that arrays of these lengths 2^k-1 for k = 1,2,... produce the "nice" symmetrical binary searches.

Mergesort splits the data 2 ways at each step. Again, it works with all data lengths. But in this case there's no "middle" element.  So here at the base we are sorting 2 sublists of length 1, then combining the results at higher levels:

```
base     1 + 1 = 2 
level 1  2 + 2 = 4
level 2  4 + 4 = 8
level 3  8 + 7 = 16
```

So here the "nice" data lengths are powers of 2, 2^k for k = 1,2,3...

Comment: Binary search can be done on both a tree and an array. But if the data is sorted your best approach is an array, because of the low cost and so on.

Comment: @DerMolly That's not true by any standard definition of binary search. See for example the first line of the Wikipedia page on this topic, which gives a couple of authoritative references. A way to see the difference is that a binary search is _always_ O(log n), where a search in a binary search tree can be O(n)

Comment: I guess I'm confusing BS and AVL Trees here.

Comment: I think I meant to say binary search trees.